# scala futures execution in parallel using for-loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, concurrent.futures

```
package p1
import scala.util.Failure
import scala.util.Success
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object modCheck extends App {

  def getStudentRoolNo(name: String) = Future {
    println("getStudentRoolNo")
    name match {
      case "name1" => 1
      case "name2" => 2
      case _       => throw new Exception("No doesnt exist")
    }
  }

  def getRank(roolNo: Int) = Future {
    println("getRank")
    Thread.sleep(500)
    roolNo match {
      case 1 => "1"
      case 2 => "2"
      case _ => throw new Exception("No roolNo exist")
    }
  }

  def getDetails(roolNo: Int) = Future {
    println("getDetails")
    roolNo match {
      case 1 => "details 1"
      case 2 => "Details 2"
      case _ => throw new Exception("No details exist")
    }
  }

  def getStudentRecord(name: String) = {
    for {
      rollNo <- getStudentRoolNo(name)
      rank <- getRank(rollNo)
      details <- getDetails(rollNo)
    } yield (rank + details)

  }

  getStudentRecord("name1").onComplete {
    case Success(ground) => println(s"got my Details $ground")
    case Failure(ex)     => println("Exception!" + ex)
  }

  Thread.sleep(2000)

}
```

I want to execute functions `getrank` and `getDetails` in parallel in below code(once the `getStudentRollNo` is returned). How can I achieve this?

I Tried below way, It seems it still executing in sequentially

Please let me know , How to execute in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Future starts computation when it's created.

`for (a <- x; b <- y) yield ???` is desugared to `x.flatMap(a => y.map(b => ???))`
`flatMap()` and `map()` execute it's argument after a Future is completed.

`getDetails()` can start before completion of `getRank()` by separating creation of `Future` and `flatMap()` invocation.

```
for {
    rollNo <- getStudentRoolNo(name)
    rankFuture = getRank(rollNo)
    detailsFuture = getDetails(rollNo)
    rank <- rankFuture
    details <- detailsFuture
  } yield (rank + details)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have probable guessed, your current code does not make calls to getRank and getDetails in parallel, since its inside for-comprehension. Its a syntactic sugar for `map` operation. To achieve parallelism you need to create two futures outside for-comprehension.

```
val student = getStudentRollNo(name)
val detailsFuture = student map {s => getRank(rollNo) }
val rankFuture = student map {s => getDetails(rollNo) }

for {
  rank <- rankFuture
  details <- detailsFuture
} yield (rank + details)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am checking more towards writing the code inside the for-loop (As my actual complicated logic is much into it, Now adopting the above solution might be little difficult), I had modified the Question, why in this case also it is executing sequentially ?

Comment: Then may be move `rankFuture = getRank(rollNo)` and subsequent lines to yield part. That will reduce the clutter and will ensure that both futures are executed in parallel

Comment: for {
    rollNo <- getStudentRoolNo(name)
    rankFuture = getRank(rollNo)
    detailsFuture = getDetails(rollNo)
    rank <- rankFuture
    details <- detailsFuture
  } yield (rank + details)  - Its working this way, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `zip` in your for-comprehension to run two Futures in parallel:

```
  def getStudentRecord(name: String) = {
    for {
      rollNo <- getStudentRoolNo(name)
      rankRollNo <- getRank(rollNo) zip getDetails(rollNo)
    } yield rankRollNo
  }
```

In the above `getRank` and `getDetails` are run simultaneously and the result is a string tuple. If you want to yield a single string, you will need to separate `rankRollNo` into its separate components:

```
yield rankRollNo._1 + rankRollNo._2
```